# jQuery - Look for a specific word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, contains

I am trying to display different content on wp post depending on a metabox (Dropdown)'s value. So if I had "Video", "Code" and "Image" available as options in the dropdown, I though of making a hidden div that would say "Video", "Code" or "Image" depending on selected one. Then I need jQuery (or Javascript) to look at the hidden div for ether word, and show/hide some div's.

Here is some code I have so far.

```
if (jQuery("div.type:contains('Video')")) {
jQuery(".Code").hide();
jQuery(".Image").hide();
}
```

But I need is to hide all div's except the correct one.

**Example**

**HTML**

```
<div class="type">video</div>
<div class="Video">Video Here</div>
<div class="Code">Code Here</div>
<div class="Image">Image Here</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
if (jQuery("div.type:contains('video')")) {
jQuery(".Video").show();
jQuery(".Code").hide();
jQuery(".Image").hide();
}
if (jQuery("div.type:contains('code')")) {
jQuery(".Video").hide();
jQuery(".Code").show();
jQuery(".Image").hide();
}
if (jQuery("div.type:contains('image')")) {
jQuery(".Video").hide();
jQuery(".Code").hide();
jQuery(".Image").show();
}
```

Why is this not working?

Look at jsfiddle whatever is entered into `<div class="type">` it will show `<div class="Image">Image Here</div>`

jsfiddle Link [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/aled2305/uREUT/161/)

Comment: Look at jsfiddle whatever is entered into `<div class="type">` it will show `<div class="Image">Image Here</div>`

Comment: Yes sure, sorry for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to check the returned jQuery object for it's length:

```
if (jQuery("div.type:contains('video')").length) {
  jQuery(".Video").show();
  jQuery(".Code").hide();
  jQuery(".Image").hide();
}
```

See this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uREUT/165/)...

To go into a bit more detail, the problem was that all of your `if` statements were returning true because all *jQuery selectors* return *jQuery objects*, whether they are empty or not. The `if` statement was evaluating to `true` because you we simply asking if the *jQuery object* was not `undefined` or `false`. A *jQuery object* is neither of these things. Remember to always check the `length` of a jQuery object when trying to determine if anything was found.

**Update**

In terms of showing nothing when there is nothing in the `div.type`, you could simply hide everything before your `if` statements evaluate. Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uREUT/170/)...

Comment: That's it perfect. Just one more thing. If neither Video, Code or Image is entered into type, how can I have nothing to display? Right now it will show all?

Comment: Thanks for that and especially the full explanation of what and why I was incorrect.

Comment: No problem. Just a final note that what you're doing can be greatly shortened by a slight restructure, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uREUT/173/)...

Answer (score 1):

```
if (jQuery("div.type:contains('video')").length > 0) {
jQuery(".Video").show();
jQuery(".Code").hide();
jQuery(".Image").hide();
}
if (jQuery("div.type:contains('code')").length > 0) {
jQuery(".Video").hide();
jQuery(".Code").show();
jQuery(".Image").hide();
}
if (jQuery("div.type:contains('image')").length > 0) {
jQuery(".Video").hide();
jQuery(".Code").hide();
jQuery(".Image").show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Minified Version

```
 var a=jQuery("div.type").html();
 $(".Video,.Code,.Image").hide();
 jQuery("."+a).show();
```

Working Fiddle Here

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uREUT/171/)

Answer (score 1):

I would change your html to look something more like this:

```
<div class="type" style="display:none">image</div>
<div class="post video">Video Here</div>
<div class="post code">Code Here</div>
<div class="post image">Image Here</div>
```

and use the following javascript code:

```
var type = jQuery('.type').text().trim();

jQuery('.post').hide().filter('.' + type).show();
```

[Here's a fiddle of the working code.](http://jsfiddle.net/THEtheChad/K3aYX/)

Answer (score 0):

Change =>`<div class="Code">Code Here</div>` TO `<div class="type">Code Here</div>`

```
<div class="type">video</div>
<div class="type">Code Here</div>
<div class="Image">Image Here</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uREUT/162/)